# Haskell not displaying result on Windows

Tags: haskell

I'm facing a strange problem.
I've installed Haskell platform for Windows, and I don't know why, a simple program like this, just doesn't work. It compiles ok, but doesn't return the print to the screen.
What am I doing wrong?

```
main = do
        io <- readFile "text.txt"
        let blabla = lines io
        print blabla
```

Thanks

Comment: What shell are you running the program in? Dos (Command Promt/cmd.exe)? MSYS/MinGW? Cygwin?

Comment: Does a simple `main = putStrLn "Hello, world"` work for you? The next step I suggest is to put `putStrLn` statements between each line of our program to trace execution.

Comment: It doesn't work. Compiles ok, but keeps displaying Main>

Comment: I'm opening the file Test.hs directly, using the Haskell platform (Ghci.exe)

Comment: @f400 that's the interactive mode... You aren't compiling it to an executable. Try :main inside ghci to run it, or you can compile it with ghc foo.hs

Comment: To run the program type `main` at the prompt (followed by Enter/Return).

Comment: @user5402 Yeah thanks a lot now working! It's a bit awkard I know, but in Ubuntu, no need to do that, it displays automatically. Sometimes when you get back to windows, strange things happens (feeling like a newbie right now :X)